# Html text with overflowing whitespace inside grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I have added text inside a grid in React.js. In this Grid component from Material UI I am rendering different components. Sometimes i need to split the view in two halves therefore the 6half/12full width conditional.

When the Paper(elevated div) component (see beneath) is added to the left- or rightPane in the Grid, the width of the page becomes huge, a lot whitespace over the screen, so it becomes scrollable to the sides. Even though it should follow the grid specified 6/12 half size. The text infact is displayed properly inside its grid but huge amount of whitespace added between the grid items. Like the text would leak out and give extra width.

If i set a fixed with for the text/html component it won't make the huge whitespace that long. This Happens only in Safari and only with this text/html component, works like a charm with other jsx components. In Chrome there is also a little squeezing padding added to the component beside it but not that huge. What might be going on and how to trap the html/text inside the div or any other suggestions?

Parent Grid rendered part:

```
<div className={cssStyles.container}>
  <Grid container direction="column" >
    {
      leftPane && (
        <Grid item xs={rightPane ? 6 : 12}>
          <Grid container  wrap="nowrap">
            <Grid item>
              <VerticalMenu
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs>
              {renderLeftPane()}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )
    }
    {
      rightPane && (
        <Grid item  xs={leftPane ? 6 : 12}>
          <Grid container  wrap="nowrap">
            <Grid item xs>
              {renderRightPane()}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <VerticalMenu
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )
    }
  </Grid>
```

Childs rendered part that messes up the page when used in renderLeftPane() or renderRightPane()

```
<Paper >
  <div className={someFixedWidhtHereHelpsSome}>
    <h1>Inledning</h1>
    <p>
      Osanno- likt nog överlevde han färden 572 meter upp
      i luften och kunde efter en hård fallskärmslandning
      konstatera att han hade över- bevisat
      alla pessimister som hade förutspått hans undergång.
      Det var emellertid inte bara en allmän våghalsighet
      och raketintresse som motiverade honom.
    </p>
    <p>
      Redan Eratosthenes (276–194 f.Kr.)
      kunde bevisa att jorden var rund och
      dessutom uppskatta dess storlek med förvånansvärd
      precision. Han gjorde det genom att
      jämföra skuggors..
    </p>
    <p>
      Redan Eratosthenes (276–194 f.Kr.)
      kunde bevisa att jorden var rund och
      dessutom uppskatta dess storlek med förvånansvärd
      precision. Han gjorde det genom att
      jämföra skuggors vinklar på olika avlägsna platser,
      ett experiment..
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, changed top grid container from column to row: `<Grid container direction="row">`